# How can I prevent a potential security hazard of using the return value of assignment expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, security

In C#, assignment expressions return the value of the LHS operand as a value:

```
int i;
while ((i = foo()) > 5) { ... }
```

This is often convenient and also idiomatic in C style languages. However, it can also lead to difficult to spot bugs, for instance:

```
if ((options == (__WCLONE|__WALL)) && (current.hasUid = true)) retval = -EINVAL;
// Also consider the case of a nullable bool
```

Especially in security critical code, I would like to at least generate a warning when compiling code that uses this language features.

How should I go about this? Do I have to create a custom rule for a code checking tool?

**Edited to fix:** Earlier, the bugged example was mistakenly using an int assignment instead of a bool assignment.

**Update:** I agree that `x = true` is redundant and invites the above bug. Well written code should not exhibit the conditions necessary to allow such a mistake.

In particular I would like to make sure those conditions do no occur, by checking (in an automated manner) for the involved issues. This increases the chance of catching the problem before it gets into prod.

Comment: How about posting a [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) in c#

Comment: @L.B I'm not sure how that would help here? Isn't the important information visible in the example lines?

Comment: No, I just wanted to see a concrete compilable code where you think you may have problem. If you can't generate it, you don't have a problem...

Comment: Don't compare explicitly with `true` or `false`.

Comment: The line `while ((int i = foo()) > 5)` doesn't even compile. You have to declare `i` before the `while`.

Comment: I tried to accommodate your comments in the recent edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mormegil points out, the idiomatic way for C# at least, is to just evaluate the property and not compare it to true (e.g. `current.hasUid`) - though for `bool?` comparisons you may want to do `nullableBool == true` instead of `nullableBool ?? false`.

If that still is not enough for you, you can force the C# compiler to make the situation an error by enabling "Treat Warnings as Errors" in the Build section of your project's properties, and entering the following error code which represents [Warning CS0665](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sde1ax%28v=vs.90%29.aspx): **0665**

Comment: I vaguely recall Eric Lippert had a nice post on the dangers of nullable bools in this particular environment, I'm trying to find it. It is good that you mention this.

Answer (score 5):

First and foremost, writing `if (aBoolVar == true)` is redundant. Write just `if (aBoolVar)` (and instead of `if (aBoolVar == false)`, write `if (!aBoolVar)`.)

Using [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) in C# hurts readability for no reason. `if (val = 0)` won't compile at all (well, unless `val` is a variable of type `GunThatShootsBothForwardAndBackwardSimultaneously` which has implicit conversion operators from `int` and to `bool`...), so this is not an issue.